# Checking if a select tag has been answered

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a working script that checks all inputs that have the class "required", it detects if the input has content and then passes the answers to Googles Invisible Recaptcha.

I'm running into an issue with select drop downs.

The following JS is an example that works with the text:

```
var questions = document.getElementsByClassName('required');
var valid = true;

for (var i=0; valid && i<questions.length; i++) {
    if (!questions[i].value.trim()) {
        valid = false;
    }
}
```

A sample of one of my dropdowns are:

```
<select id="q6" class="required" name="designation">
      <!-- Disabled -->
      <option disabled selected>Select one of the following:</option>
      <!-- Options -->
      <option value="#">Regisitered Nurse</option>
      <option value="#">Regisitered Practical Nurse</option>
      <option value="#">Personal Support Worker (Developmental Service Worker)</option>
      <option value="#">Nursing Student (Completed First Year)</option>
      <!-- Options // END -->
</select>
```

I was wondering if anyone knows how to add the function to detect an unanswered select drop down to my script above. It would be excellent if we could make this work with a "file" input as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding: value="" to your first select option, so by default it is empty, and will fail the validation check.

```js
let validate = function() {
  var questions = document.getElementsByClassName('required');
  var valid = true;

  for (var i = 0; valid && i < questions.length; i++) {
    if (!questions[i].value.trim()) {
      valid = false;
    }
  }

  console.log(valid);

}
```

```html
<input id="q5" class="required" name="name" type="text" />
<select id="q6" class="required" name="designation">
      <!-- Disabled -->
      <option disabled selected value="">Select one of the following:</option>
      <!-- Options -->
      <option value="#">Regisitered Nurse</option>
      <option value="#">Regisitered Practical Nurse</option>
      <option value="#">Personal Support Worker (Developmental Service Worker)       </option>
      <option value="#">Nursing Student (Completed First Year)</option>
      <!-- Options // END -->
</select>
<button onclick="validate();">Validate</button>
```

Comment: Inversely, you could also check if your selected option value is not equal to '#'

Answer (score 0):

You can validate using the **selectedIndex** attribute of the select element and then try getting the **value attribute** from the selected option if any:

```js
validate = function(){

  // Validate Select Elements
  var selectElements = document.getElementsByTagName("select");
  for(var i = 0; i < selectElements.length; i++)
  {
    var selectedIndex = selectElements[i].selectedIndex;
    if (selectedIndex < 0 || !selectElements[i][selectedIndex].getAttribute("value")) 
    {
     return false;      
    }
  }
  
  // Validate other elements here...
  
  return true;
}

//Clear the selection of the first select element to show how validations work for empty selection
document.getElementById('select1').selectedIndex = -1;
```

```html
<select id="select1">
      <option value="1">Option 1</option>
      <option value="2">Option 2</option>
      <option value="">Option With Empty Value Attribute</option>
      <option>Option With No Value Attribute</option>
</select>
<br>

<select id="select2">
      <option value="1">Option 1</option>
      <option value="2">Option 2</option>
      <option value="">Option With Empty Value Attribute</option>
      <option>Option With No Value Attribute</option>
</select>
<br><br>

<button onclick="alert(validate());">Validate</button>
```